# open camera on flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

hello i`m trying to open camera on flutter app but i'm getting I/flutter (12909): NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'name' was called on null.
I/flutter (12909): Receiver: null
I/flutter (12909): Tried calling: name

here is my code

```
`import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  // Ensure that plugin services are initialized so that `availableCameras()`
  // can be called before `runApp()`
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Obtain a list of the available cameras on the device.
  final cameras = await availableCameras();

  // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
  final firstCamera = cameras.first;

  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: TakePictureScreen(
        // Pass the appropriate camera to the TakePictureScreen widget.
        camera: firstCamera,
      ),
    ),
  );
}

// A screen that allows users to take a picture using a given camera.
class TakePictureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final CameraDescription camera;

  const TakePictureScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.camera,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  TakePictureScreenState createState() => TakePictureScreenState();
}

class TakePictureScreenState extends State<TakePictureScreen> {
  CameraController _controller;
  Future<void> _initializeControllerFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // To display the current output from the Camera,
    // create a CameraController.
    _controller = CameraController(
      // Get a specific camera from the list of available cameras.
      widget.camera,
      // Define the resolution to use.
      ResolutionPreset.medium,
    );

    // Next, initialize the controller. This returns a Future.
    _initializeControllerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose of the controller when the widget is disposed.
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Take a picture')),
      // Wait until the controller is initialized before displaying the
      // camera preview. Use a FutureBuilder to display a loading spinner
      // until the controller has finished initializing.
      body: FutureBuilder<void>(
        future: _initializeControllerFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If the Future is complete, display the preview.
            return CameraPreview(_controller);
          } else {
            // Otherwise, display a loading indicator.
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        // Provide an onPressed callback.
        onPressed: () async {
          // Take the Picture in a try / catch block. If anything goes wrong,
          // catch the error.
          try {
            // Ensure that the camera is initialized.
            await _initializeControllerFuture;

            // Attempt to take a picture and get the file `image`
            // where it was saved.
            final image = await _controller.takePicture();

            // If the picture was taken, display it on a new screen.
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => DisplayPictureScreen(
                  // Pass the automatically generated path to
                  // the DisplayPictureScreen widget.
                  imagePath: image?.path,
                ),
              ),
            );
          } catch (e) {
            // If an error occurs, log the error to the console.
            print(e);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

// A widget that displays the picture taken by the user.
class DisplayPictureScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String imagePath;

  const DisplayPictureScreen({Key key, this.imagePath}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Display the Picture')),
      // The image is stored as a file on the device. Use the `Image.file`
      // constructor with the given path to display the image.
      body: Image.file(File(imagePath)),
    );
  }
}
```

From [https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera#3-create-and-initialize-the-cameracontroller`](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera#3-create-and-initialize-the-cameracontroller%60)